# How to create new query method at repository with or without ElasticSearch and Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-boot

I have 2 models, one called Employee and another one User,
Employee has one field pointing to User, one to one relationship.

My problem is that i need one query method to find the Employee that has the user with certain id. I need to find the Employee with certain User id.

I know the default query methods: .findOne, .findAll, but i need to create one, alright? how i can do that? i searched a lot but probably i am missing something. I didn't found how to do a query like that.

Thanks

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation)? . Add something like `Employee findByUserId(long id)`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, i have read. But at first time probably i did something wrong, tried again and it worked. Thanks!